# Warning: Cannot update a component (`App`) while rendering a different component (`C2`)

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-state

I have that problem, I have 3 componeents : App, C1, C2 and I am trying to pass a variable from App to C2 through C1.

Here is App.js :

```
import { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import C1 from "./C1";

const App = () =>{

  const [myVar, setMyVar] = useState("")

  return(
    <>
    <h1>Test</h1>
    <C1 myVar={myVar} setMyVar={(test) => {setMyVar(test)}} />
    </>
  )
}

export default App
```

Here is C1.js :

```
import C2 from "./C2";

const C1 = (props) => {
  console.log(props.myVar);
  //props.setMyVar("Hola")
  console.log(props.myVar);

  return (
    <>
      <h1>Hello</h1>
      <C2
        myVar={props.myVar}
        setMyVar={(test) => {
          props.setMyVar(test);
        }}
      />
    </>
  );
};

export default C1;
```

and the last C2.js :

```
const C2 = (props) =>{
  console.log(props.myVar)
  props.setMyVar("Manger")
  console.log(props.myVar)

return(
  <h1>Easy</h1>
);

}

export default C2;
```

But I saw in the console the following error :

`Warning: Cannot update a component (`App`) while rendering a different component (`C2`). To locate the bad setState() call inside` C2`, follow the stack trace as described in https://reactjs.org/link/setstate-in-render C2@https://jnulps.csb.app/src/C2.js:13:3 C1@https://jnulps.csb.app/src/C1.js:17:3 App@https://jnulps.csb.app/src/App.js:26:41`

Here is the full project : [The full code](https://codesandbox.io/s/keen-zeh-jnulps?file=/src/App.js:0-327)

Could you help me please ?

Thank you very much !

Answer (score 1):

Because in **C2.js** you setState through `props.setMyVar("Manger")` is reason to make React infinite render at the same time when state change, to fix it put `props.setMyVar("Manger")` inside **useEffect()**:

```
const C2 = (props) =>{
  console.log(props.myVar)
  useEffect(() => {
     props.setMyVar("Manger")
  }, [])
  console.log(props.myVar)

  return(
  <h1>Easy</h1>
);

}

export default C2;
```

Answer (score 1):

The error message will be displayed if parent (App) states are set while rendering children (C2).

Specifically, while trying to render C2, React will run `props.setState("Manger")` which will also trigger a re-render of App. One way to fix this is to put `props.setState("manger")` of C2 inside a `useEffect`, or put it in some element's on-click handler (if you have a specific use case).

Another thing to note is that, `console.log` right after `setState` will not get you the most updated value, because `setState` is asynchronous